# Postgres status is Active but does not accept connection

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-12

I have a postgres 12 database running on ubuntu server 20.4.

This database has been long switched off and now it will be reignited again. So after changing the `listen_addresses = '*'` and creating `"host    all    all   0.0.0.0/0   md5"` on pg_hba.conf, I reboot the server. I notice that the postgres service does not run.
I check the location of the postgres directory. It is on the **"/etc/postgresql/12/main/"**. But the default directory for postgres user is on **/var/lib/postgresql**. when I check the **/var/lib/postgresql/12**, its basically empty. Look at the pic below :
[image: Here it is].

So I start the database using `sudo service postgresql start`. The DB starts but It does not accept the connection, even if I do it on the server directly (via putty).
[image: Here is the error].

Here is the  status using `sudo service postgresql status` [image: status]

I try to search the **".s.PGSQL.5432"** on **/var/run/postgresql** but can not be found.

Here is what I have done :

- `ps aux | grep '[b]in/postgres'`  -- shows nothing
- ps -ef | grep postgres : Gives out [image: this result]
- `dpkg -l | grep postgres` : Gives out [image: this]
- As root user, I type in `pg_lsclusters`. Resulting [image: this]
- I try to start the cluster, `sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main start`. Gives out [image: this]

Questions :

1. On the `sudo service postgresql status` picture, what is "`disabled`" (the one marked with yellow box) indicating ? Whereas, the other normal databases on different servers show "`enabled`".
2. Whats is going on with this database ? I try to check the log `$root /var/log/postgresql` too, but mostly it is about unable to receive WALs. [image: Here is the picture].
   The latest line on the log file is about a year ago

thanks

Comment: The standby server got out of sync and was shutdown and obviously abandoned. You can probably delete that cluster.

Comment: Ok. I drop it using : `pg_dropcluster 12 main --stop`. It says :
**Warning: corrupted cluster: data directory does not exist**
@LaurensAlbe

Comment: Great. Mission accomplished.

Comment: It still does not accept a connection.  @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: If there is no database cluster any more, of course there is nothing to accept a connection. Try to connect to a database server that actually exists.

Comment: The problem is, the PostgreSQL service status indicates active. I am assuming that since there is no more cluster, the database becomes single again and can accept connections. Wrong assumption ? thanks  @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Yes, wrong assumption. Cluster = instance. If the instance is not running, all databases are down. If the instance is removed, all databases are gone.

Comment: so, how do I start the database as single again ? i am confused. If the instance is not running, then why the `postgre service active`? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: You cannot start it, the data are deleted now. But that is no big damage, because the server hasn't been running for a year and was hopelessly behind. It look like `systemd` is confused and not aware that the server is not running. You have to create a new database cluster or take a new base backup to create a standby. See the documentation.

Comment: So, if i want to make it single again without clustering, what do i have to do  'purging' it and reinstall? Sorry for my noob question, iam still learning. Thanks @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: I won't provide a tutorial how to get started with PostgreSQL, and indeed that exceeds the scope of a Stackoverflow answer. I recommend reading the documentation about `initdb`.

Comment: yups. that's super fine, at least I have something to read. thanks for the `initdb` tips. :)